# maven-jaxb2-plugin class generation from xsd (Version Error)

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd

My pom.xml,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.rajkishan</groupId>
<artifactId>RESTful-Swagger</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<name>RESTful-Swagger</name>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.rajkishan.Application</start-class>
</properties>

 <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

 <build>
<plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>Greeting.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>com.rajkishan.xmlgen</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

</plugins>
```

When i build using maven in "Netbeans", this works fine.

But if i use in Eclipse Luna, it gives error like;

> Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener

But it works if i change the version to `0.12.1`, like below;

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>Greeting.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>com.rajkishan.xmlgen</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong here? Am i missing something?

NOTE: I use jdk1.8 in eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Eclipse was started with the jre, not the jdk. After changing eclipse to start with the jdk the it runs fine...

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency and try again -

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried the dependency with Version 0.12.3. Didn't work. Same Error Message.

Comment: Have you tried the <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId> as well ? Also there is this Github issue which talks about the same thing - https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/15 . You can also have a look at it as well.